# How to write contents of a rails database to external file

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, external

I'm trying to have rails send the contents of my database to an external textfile.
I wanted this done everytime a new user is created.

However, when i try to do the following in my user.rb model file,

```
before_save :write_data

def write_data()
    File.open("data.txt", "w") do |myfile|
        myfile.write(User.all)
    end
end
```

It doesn't write the actual contents of the database, instead, it displays something like this

```
User:0x109858540
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: You might find it instructive to run `script/console`, and then run `require 'user' ; User.all()`.

Answer (score 3):

User.all returns a ruby Object, and likely the `write` method says "Hey, I am expecting a string, this isn't one, so I'll call the `to_s` method".

So you need to figure out how to turn your user list into some form that you can write to your text file, which is known as serialization.  Ah, but in what format?  XML?  JSON? YAML? ... or the dreaded CSV format?  There are built in classes to convert ActiveRecord objects to various formats, and gems to handle others.  So I'll assume you will call a `to_something` method.

Also, `User.all` means you want to write your entire user table (every record) to a corresponding file. (I think you might want to ask yourself why, but that's a different topic).  So you'll probably need to iterate over each of the user records.

Code probably looks more like

```
def write_data   # It's ruby -- don't need no stinkin' empty parenthesis!! :-)
  my_file = File.open("data.txt", "w")
  User.all.each do |u|
    my_file.write u.to_something
  end
end
```

You might need to put a newline at the end of each row.